# Swift 3 Repeat Spawning of SKNode

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have a SKNode that spawns and moves across the screen. It all works as intended. I am, however, unsure how to make this occur multiple times. My desire is for the 'barrels' to spawn every 2 seconds. You can see my attempt in the code below.

```
class GameScene : SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var Player = SKSpriteNode()
var Ground = SKSpriteNode()
var Roof = SKSpriteNode()
var Background = SKSpriteNode()
let Obstacle1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Fire Barrel 1")

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    // Create Background Color
    backgroundColor = bgColor

    // Set World Gravity
    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -4.0)

    // Create Player
    Player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Player")
    Player.setScale(0.5)
    Player.position = CGPoint(x: -self.frame.width / 2 + 100, y: -Player.frame.height / 2)

    self.addChild(Player)

    // Create Ground
    Ground = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BGTileBtm")
    Ground.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0.5)
    Ground.position = CGPoint(x: -self.frame.width / 2, y: -self.frame.height / 2)

    self.addChild(Ground)

    // Create Roof
    Roof = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "BGTileTop")
    Roof.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1,y: 1)
    Roof.position = CGPoint(x: -self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2 - Roof.frame.height)
    Roof.zRotation = CGFloat(M_PI)

    self.addChild(Roof)

    // Set Physics Rules
    Player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "Player"), size: Player.size)
    Player.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = true
    Player.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = false

    Ground.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ground"), size: Ground.size)
    Ground.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    Ground.physicsBody!.isDynamic = false

    // Obstacle
    func addObstacle1(){

        Obstacle1.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: -self.frame.height / 2 + Obstacle1.frame.height)
        Obstacle1.zPosition = 1
        addChild(Obstacle1)

        let distance = CGVector(dx: -self.frame.width, dy: 0)
        let moveDistance = SKAction.move(by: distance, duration: 5)
        Obstacle1.run(moveDistance)

    }

    let spawnObstacles = SKAction(addObstacle1())
    let delay = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2)
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([delay, spawnObstacles])

    run(SKAction.repeatForever(sequence))

}
```

Comment: What doesn't work about the current code?

Comment: It spawns and moves once only. I was hoping the repeat forever addition would cause it to spawn and move repeatedly.

Comment: Try setting the obstacles texture in the function `addObstacle` rather than globally. You can keep the declaration of obstacle global, just set its texture in the function

Comment: Thanks for the input but that doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Try enabling nodeCount in the GameViewController to see if they're being added or not

Comment: The node count starts at 5 and doesn't change.

Comment: Could it be something to do with only having one child?

Answer (score 0):

Begin with putting the `addObstacle` outside of `didMove` method. Then put the following in your `didMove` method:

```
_ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(addObstacle1), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

It should repeat your `addObstacle` every two seconds :)